# Error: use of undeclared identifier 'PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST' cargo build liblmdb-sys for aarch64-linux-android target

Tags: android, c, rust, rust-cargo, lmdb

I am trying to compile a [rust project](https://github.com/mimblewimble/grin-wallet/tree/master/libwallet) into an Android target (aarch64-linux-android).

From the comments in the [lmdb code](https://github.com/LMDB/lmdb/blob/ad8488cfac644d7a289e428ab3c403c859d844cb/libraries/liblmdb/mdb.c#L246), it seems to need to run the compilation

> `"aarch64-linux-android-gcc" "-O2" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-o" "/Users/username/grin-wallet/target/aarch64-linux-android/release/build/liblmdb-sys-7a2d430dc3c9f3e3/out/mdb/libraries/liblmdb/mdb.o" "-c" "mdb/libraries/liblmdb/mdb.c"`

with an additional `-DMDB_USE_ROBUST=0` flag. Is this configurable from either the `cargo build` command or adding something to Cargo.toml?

The error I am getting is:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `liblmdb-sys v0.2.2`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/username/grin-wallet/target/release/build/liblmdb-sys-b6bfc7b665736f9b/build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
--- stdout
TARGET = Some("aarch64-linux-android")
TARGET = Some("aarch64-linux-android")
HOST = Some("x86_64-apple-darwin")
TARGET = Some("aarch64-linux-android")
TARGET = Some("aarch64-linux-android")
HOST = Some("x86_64-apple-darwin")
CC_aarch64-linux-android = None
CC_aarch64_linux_android = None
TARGET_CC = None
CC = None
TARGET = Some("aarch64-linux-android")
HOST = Some("x86_64-apple-darwin")
CFLAGS_aarch64-linux-android = None
CFLAGS_aarch64_linux_android = None
TARGET_CFLAGS = None
CFLAGS = None
DEBUG = Some("false")
running: "aarch64-linux-android-gcc" "-O2" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-o" "/Users/username/grin-wallet/target/aarch64-linux-android/release/build/liblmdb-sys-7a2d430dc3c9f3e3/out/mdb/libraries/liblmdb/mdb.o" "-c" "mdb/libraries/liblmdb/mdb.c"
cargo:warning=mdb/libraries/liblmdb/mdb.c:4625:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pthread_mutexattr_setrobust' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
cargo:warning=                        || (rc = pthread_mutexattr_setrobust(&mattr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST))
cargo:warning=                                 ^
cargo:warning=mdb/libraries/liblmdb/mdb.c:4625:49: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST'
cargo:warning=                        || (rc = pthread_mutexattr_setrobust(&mattr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST))
cargo:warning=                                                                     ^
cargo:warning=mdb/libraries/liblmdb/mdb.c:9821:33: warning: unused parameter 'env' [-Wunused-parameter]
cargo:warning=mdb_env_get_maxkeysize(MDB_env *env)
cargo:warning=                                ^
cargo:warning=mdb/libraries/liblmdb/mdb.c:10002:10: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pthread_mutex_consistent' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
cargo:warning=                        rc2 = mdb_mutex_consistent(mutex);
cargo:warning=                              ^
cargo:warning=mdb/libraries/liblmdb/mdb.c:351:37: note: expanded from macro 'mdb_mutex_consistent'
cargo:warning=#define mdb_mutex_consistent(mutex)     pthread_mutex_consistent(mutex)
cargo:warning=                                        ^
cargo:warning=3 warnings and 1 error generated.
exit code: 1
```

Comment: It seems, that you are using the cc crate. It would be good to see your code that compiles the library, e.g. your `build.rs`.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have all the android build targets installed:

```
rustup target add aarch64-linux-android armv7-linux-androideabi i686-linux-android
```

Then `install cargo-ndk`

```
cargo install cargo-ndk
```

Now you need to export a number of variables in the terminal that will be used by the build.

If you are using pkg-config then

```
export PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS=1
```

The root directory of the NDK

```
export NDK_HOME=the_path_to_the_ndk
```

The platform version

```
export NDK_API_LEVEL=the_api_level
```

Note that the compilers must be specified as clang for newer versions of the NDK since GCC was deprecated in the android toolchain and is no longer present (some projects try to reference GCC by default)

```
export CC=$NDK_HOME/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android$NDK_API_LEVEL-clang
export CXX=$NDK_HOME/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android$NDK_API_LEVEL-clang++
```

Then the rest of the variables

```
export AR=$NDK_HOME/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ar
export AS=$NDK_HOME/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-as
export LD=$NDK_HOME/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ld
export RANLIB=$NDK_HOME/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ranlib
export STRIP=$NDK_HOME/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-strip
```

You were on the right track in thinking -DMDB_USE_ROBUST=0, it just needed to be passed to the compiler flags

```
export CFLAGS=-DMDB_USE_ROBUST=0
```

Then in your rust project, you will need to create a .config directory in the same directory as your .toml file. Within the .config directory, you will need to create a config file.

In the config file you will need to specify the relevant build targets for each target you need built (replace NDK_HOME and NDK_API_LEVEL with their respective values)

```
[target.aarch64-linux-android]
ar = "<NDK_HOME>/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ar"
linker = "<NDK_HOME>/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android<NDK_API_LEVEL>-clang"
```

You should then be able to build successfully with

```
cargo ndk --target aarch64-linux-android --android-platform $NDK_API_LEVEL -- build --release
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't just build and targeting to linex-android, another way to do this is develop your app via Android Studio or with Flutter

Comment: Despite asking for getting rewarded is pretty rude: what is *linex-android*? Your post needs to be extended. *A lot*. So many crucial information are missing, e.g. how to include the rust code into Android Studio or Flutter.

Comment: Pardon? What exactly are you trying to tell me?